# Kotlin String format

Tags: android, строки, kotlin

Делаю приложение и хочу чтоб, в `textView` у меня например  выводило `70%`. Для этого в `resourse` в `string` я написал так: `<string name="**_1010mb**" >%1s%</string>` и хотел чтоб при выдаче какого нибудь числа у меня выводило например `70%`.

В `Main Activity` я прописываю так: `val humidity = getString(R.string.**_1010mb**,response.body()?.main?.humidity)` (и `toString` попробовал подставить).

Но у меня выходит ошибка: `Format String _1010mb is not valid format string so it should not be passed to String.format` - Как это исправить?

И в `receyclerview adapter:`  тоже проблема `itemView.gradOne.text = getString(R.string._18,data.temp.day.toInt())` выходит такая ошибка:

`TypedArrayUtils.getString can only be called from within the same library group prefix (referenced groupId=androidx.core with prefix androidx from groupId=AsyncTascRetrofit)`

Comment: `%1s%%` (экранируйте второй %)

Comment: Я вам отформатировал вопрос, зачем вы опять превратили его в месиво?

Comment: @ Эникейщик простите! спасибо вам!

Answer (score 2):

у вас неправильная запись `%1s%`, должно быть `%1$d%%` (забыли $), и далее вы вставляете число, в форматированном виде, поэтому вместо `$s`, необходимо использовать `$d`

Comment: спасибо вышло! а как быть с receyclerview он не видит getString

Comment: похоже у вас какой-то другой метод заимпортировался, вам нужно дёрнуть у контекста активити, context.getString

Comment: внутри RecyclerView есть ViewHolder. В нем есть itemView из которой можно достать контекст. А прокидывать туда контекст Activity не целесообразно